How SOSL filtering works?
I thought Salesforce SOSL engine searches for records in the following order:

Search full database by the keywords
Apply additional filters from WHERE clause
Apply other filters (sharing settings, role hierarchy, etc.)

But when I run the following queries, I got the following results:
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Active') AND RecordTypeId = '012J0000005P5adIAC') returns 1953 records
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Active')) returns 1953 records
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Inactive') AND RecordTypeId = '012J0000005P5adIAC') returns 1950 records
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Inactive')) returns 1950 records
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE RecordTypeId = '012J0000005P5adIAC') returns 2000 records
FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c) returns 250 records
As FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Active')) returns 1953 records, I expected FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c WHERE AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Inactive')) will return <= 47 records. Because the FIND {JAVA} returns 2000 records and the AVTRRT__Candidate_Status__c IN ('Active') filters it to 1953 records. So, the only left records out of the found 2000 are 47 records maximum. But the latter query returned much more records (1950 records). And I don't understand why.
And more frustrating result I got when I run the query FIND {JAVA} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, AVTRRT__Lat__c, AVTRRT__Lon__c) which returned only 250 records. There is just a FIND {JAVA} search without WHERE clause, so I expected to get 2000 records. And I don't understand why it returned only 250 records.
Does anybody know why it shows such a result?
